# jQuery does not trigger after ajax call on current page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My site is built on PHP. I have a "signup" page that validates if a username has already been taken. See below code:

```
$('#signup_form').find('#username').blur(function() {
    $ajax({
           url: '/login/check_username',
      type: "POST",
      data: form_data,
           success: function(result) { 
                if (result) {
                $('#username').after('<div id="bad_username"
                               style="color:red;">' +
                             '<p>username taken</p></div>');
                }
            }
     });
```

Above works just fine when I load my page site.com/signup

Naturally, it worked because jQuery was able to find "username" field and take action on blur (which I can verify by viewing the html source).

Now, what if "username" field is not rendered in html? This happens when I load my signup page on an ajax page load in which case, the browser does not know about the "username" field at all even though it displays it visually.

To summarise the happy path ->

I load -> site.com/signup 
I view source -> A field with id "username" is visible
On blur event fires and displays message if username already exists.

To summarise the problem ->

** 1 ** I go to -> site.com/some_page
within this page, I click on site.com/signup

** 2 ** Now the content of some_page is replaced via ajax and I see my "signup" form fields.

** 3 ** View Source -> "username" that I used to see in the happy path scenario now no longer present in the html source;

** 4 ** Maybe due to "username" not in html source, now nothing happens when I blur on the username. The jQuery is not called and it does not check for an existing username.

Is there a special function that tells jQuery to "find" or "load" the "username" field?

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: That's a lot of text when all you had to do was search for "delegated event handlers" on Google ?

Comment: `$('#signup_form').find('#username')` needs to exists by the time you call the blur function code. Maybe you should try to attach event after ajax load or even better: attach it to your signup page so when it loads it already handles event

Comment: pardon me but I'm very new and learning jQuery. I will lookup and try delegation... will post back if I need quicker help ;-)

Comment: juvian/adeno: I have tried below 2 but no success yet... any suggestions? find('#username').on("blur", function(){..} // find('#username').live("blur", function(){..}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you would need to change:

```
$('#signup_form').find('#username').blur(function() {
```

to:

```
$('body').on('blur', '#username', function() {
                      ^^^^^^^^^ the element you want to register the event of
   ^^^^ any containing element that already exists on page load
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeroen! That worked. Appreciate your help.

Comment: However, hypothetically if I have multiple forms how can I uniquely identify the form as I used $('#signup_form').find('#username').blur ?

Comment: @user3591355 ID's have to be unique so in this case that should not be a problem. Otherwise you would have to change `body` for the element (an ID, a class) that is already present and contains / will contain only the form / element you want to target, for example `$('#right_bar').on(....`.